# unit test using angular and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing

I created a plugin jQuery that I converted to angularjs, it works perfectly but I have some difficult with some part of the code to make unit test

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.factory('testFactory', function($window){

    var $ = $window.jQuery;
    var factory = {};
    var selector = ['.selector1', '.selector2', '.selector3'];

    factory.manipEl = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
            $(selector[i]).myFunction();
        }
    };

    return factory;
});
```

do I have to mock $window
or create a fake contain for body as ?

```
describe('myApp', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        var fixture = '<div id="selector1"></div><div id="selector2"></div>';

        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', fixture);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the thing you're testing exactly? `it('should... ', function(){});`

Comment: firstly I would like o test if selectors are in the page, after that, I'd like to test .myFunction(); wihch need to use result returned by $(selector[i]).